# postgres/bookshelf fetchAll() withRelated (getting multiple relations)

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to do a fairly complicated (at least for me)API request that involves getting an array of reports.  The report object itself has nested objects and so I am trying to pull the related data at the same time.  The report object looks like this:

```
reports: { loading: false, error: null, data: [{id:'', date:'', 
student_id:'', 
feeding:[],diapering:[], nap:[], meds:[], playTime:[], comments:[], 
supplies:[]}] }
```

I've figured out how to get one report with multiple related tables, but I haven't been able to figure out the syntax for getting an array of reports each with their own related data.

this is what I have at the moment:

```
exports.getReport = (date) => {
  console.log(id)
  return Reports.where(date)
        .fetchAll({
              withRelated: ['feeding', 'comment', 'diapering', 'nap', 'meds', 'playTime', 'supplies']
        })
        .then(report => {
              const meds = report.related('meds')
              const nap = report.related('nap')
              const feeding = report.related('feeding')
              const diapering = report.related('diapering')
              const supplies = report.related('supplies')
              const playTime = report.related('playTime')
              const comm = report.related('comment')

              const medsList = meds.map(med => {
                    return med.attributes
              })
              const napList = nap.map(n => {
                    return n.attributes
              })
              const feedingList = feeding.map(feed => {
                    return feed.attributes
              })
              console.log(feedingList)
              const diaperList = diapering.map(diaper => {
                    return diaper.attributes
              })
              const suppliesList = supplies.map(supply => {
                    return supply.attributes
              })
              const playTimeList = playTime.map(play => {
                    return play.attributes
              })
              const commentList = comm.map(com => {
                    return com.attributes
              })
              return reports
              const reports = report.models.map(rep => {
                    return rep.attributes
              })
              return [feedingList, commentList, napList, playTimeList, 
                      suppliesList, diaperList, medsList, reports]
        })
        .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
        })
   }
```

this syntax works with a

> .fetch()

, but not with the

> fetchAll()

I'm getting a

> report.related is not a function error

Comment: You say you want an array of reports, but you're limiting the fetch to a single report `id`, so how are you expecting to get multiple reports out of this?

Comment: the id in the parameter of the function is the date.  so I'm asking for all reports on a certain date. I modified it from the function I used to get a single report, so it still said id.  I changed it for clarification

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Bookshelf? I use `Model.where(/* conditions */).fetchAll({withRelated: ['stuff']})` in one application and it returns the correct values. Not sure why you're doing all those `.map` calls after you get the response though. Seems a bit redundant. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: the Model.where(date).fetchAll() ({withRelated:['stuff']}) does not return the correct values

Comment: It returns a list of these-

Comment: { '44':
      ModelBase {
        attributes: [Object],
        _previousAttributes: [Object],
        changed: {},
        relations: [Object],
        cid: 'c11',
        id: 44 },

Comment: it has the id of the report but none of the related data is included

Comment: **It is included**. That's the model object data. If you just send that to the client using `res.send(report)` you will get the correct data. Or you can call `.toJSON()` to get the output directly, but it's not necessary unless you want to `console.log` it or something. More info on the documentation: http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-toJSON

Answer (score 0):

To whoever reads this:

First the good news: I can confirm this works with Bookshelf 1.2.0:

```
  let result = await models.packages
    .fetchAll({
      require:     false,
      columns:     [
          'packages.id',
          'packages.name',
      ],
      withRelated: [
        'packageCollections',
      ],
      debug:       false,
    });
```

The bad news: the documentation is not great. This behavior indeed contradicts with the [documentation](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-static-fetchAll).

Another very big gotcha that wasted *many hours* of my time: this ORM does the joining of related entities in the JavaScript process itself, not by using SQL joins. So, if you don't include the primary key column or foreign key column that is used for any sort of joining, you won't get the relevant related data at all.

**There won't be any error or warning - of course**. You'll just be left wondering, what the heck is happening?
So, yeah, make sure you include the relevant ID columns in the columns list.

And if you can - please, just use a different, more modern ORM.